# Prove Null($A^t A$) = Null($A$)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I couldn't find anything like this (though it may have been bad searching), so:

Given that $A$ is an *m* x *n* matrix, prove that:

Null($A^t A$)= Null($A$)

I'm not sure how to prove this or which properties to use.

Comment: You need to show two things: that anything annihilated by A is annihilated by $A^TA$ and vice versa. One of these directions is obvious.

Comment: Consider the nondegeneracy of the standard euclidean inner product (for the non-obvious direction).

Comment: My closest thought is that **_Ax = 0_** is the same as **_A^t Ax = 0_**. None of this will likely be immediately obvious to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $x\in\operatorname{Null}(A)$ so we have $Ax=0$ and therefore $A^TAx=A^T\cdot 0=0$ and $x\in \operatorname{Null}(A^TA)$ and we have proven that $\operatorname {Null}(A)\subset \operatorname{Null}(A^TA)$

Now assume that $A^TAx=0$ so we have $\langle A^TAx,x\rangle=0$ where $\langle , \rangle$ is the Euclidean inner product of the space. The property of transpose leads to $\langle Ax,Ax\rangle=0$ and because the inner product is definite we have $Ax=0$ and therefore $\operatorname {Null}(A^TA)\subset \operatorname{Null}(A)$

Comment: Could you explain $\langle A^T Ax,x \rangle = \langle Ax,Ax \rangle $?

Comment: The property of transpose with relation to the inner product is $\langle x,Ax \rangle=\langle A^Tx,x\rangle$. You can prove it by developing the product with the components for instance.